# Transfer log files from root to ephemeral memory in Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, logging, amazon-ec2

I have put my Ruby on Rails application/website on Amazon Ec2 m1 large(64 bit)instance.
I am also using Nginx and Thin server as application and webserver resp. 
Now the website has gone live and it is producing a lot of request and hence logs.
I have put the application on the root directory and the problem I am facing is that it has 7.5 Gb space and the space may well get over in a couple of days.

I want to actually move the log file from the application to the ephemeral memory/mount so that it does not give any memory issues.
I however do not want to move the entire application to ephemeral memory because it is volatile and may result in data loss.

Can someone please tell me if its possible only to move only the log file from the application to ephemeral memory.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Its not memory. Its ephemeral disk storage. The difference vs EBS volumes is that its attached to the host and will be lost of the instance is stopped or fails. You can write your logs to ephemeral storage, but you will need it enabled which can only be done at launch.

Comment: @datasage Yeah it is enabled..But how do I transfer log files in the disk storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the location where you want to put your log files in the `/mnt` drive

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/logs
sudo chown ubuntu /mnt/logs
```

Now, delete the local log folder from your app (when your app and nginx are down, of course)

```
rm -R /my/app/logs
```

And create a softlink from the local location to the location on the `/mnt`

```
ln -s /mnt/logs /my/app/logs
```

You can do the same for your `ngnix` log directory.

Now you can start your server again. Logs will be saved to `/mnt/logs`.

I would like to note though, that this shouldn't replace the need to rotate those logs - use [`logrotate`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) to make sure that your log files are managed properly.

Comment: Thanks for the solution..
Can I ask you,Is ubuntu compulsory in chown command or will chown /mnt/logs do

Comment: `ubuntu` is the name of the default user in AWS's Ubuntu machines. I'm not even sure if that is necessary - as long as you give it write permissions.